# I am using MariaDB 10 on Centos 7 and cannot find the [mysqld] section in my configuration file

Tags: mariadb, centos7

- Centos 7
- MariaDB 10.6.11

Where can I find the `[mysql]` section in `/etc/my.cnf` file

This is all i found in `/etc/my.cnf` file

```
#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include *.cnf from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

I want to access database server remotely which is required to add `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in `/etc/my.cnf` file

Comment: If it's not there, then why not just add that section? It's quite common for configuration/ini files to not have all sections populated.

Comment: I've also tried adding it manually but I still can't access it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

bind-address is a server option and needs to be added in section [server],[mysqld] or [mariadbd]. Group [mysql] is a client section used e.g. by command line client.

See also: [Server Option Groups](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#server-option-groups)

The line

`!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d`

states, that my.cnf reads all configuration files from the /etc/my.cnf.d directory.

So check the configuration files in this directory. If there aren't any configuration files or none of them contains a group which will be read by server, add a new file server.cnf in /etc/my.cnf.d and add the group with bind address.